# Is the laptop screen physically damaged

Tags: laptop, display

My laptop screen has been flickering on and off for a couple of months.  I have had this laptop about four years. Please see the image attached.

The flickering used to stop after a few minutes, but yesterday suddenly a black "splodge" appeared on the screen (when I was using the laptop). I do not think it is due to a physical damage (as I look after it well) though I could be wrong.

[image]

Do I need a new graphics card/screen or do you think a pixel repair tool will do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

The panel has clearly cracked inside, which has caused the liquid to leak. It is most likely it has received physical damage at some point. [More examples:](https://www.google.com.kh/search?q=cracked+lcd+panel&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=595&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWso-YusLKAhWFg6YKHWjaCN0Q_AUIBigB)

It will need a screen panel replacement. These are often fairly generic but can vary based on their backlight and inverter requirements, and occasionally different fitments from different manufacturers.

Comment: The laptop starting flickering many months ago.  This makes me think it is just down to general wear and tear - it was a cheap laptop.  I am going to buy a new laptop.  Do you think it is general wear and tear or due to impact e.g. dropping it? I always look after my devices.

Comment: @w0051977 Could be a knock, I've seen it happen when things are on top of the laptop keybaord and the lid is shut on it. It's hard to say, but I've never seen a panel just crack without any physical contact. That's not to say it couldn't happen, perhaps a lot of heat could do it, but it's usually a knock of some kind.